# Login Popup not working when I click the Login button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the code I use to display a login popup. It is not working when I click the login button. After I reload or refresh the page login works.
Can any one please help me how can I resolve this issue?
Thanks much in advance.

View code:

```
  <form id="loginForm" class="myform" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group focus">
    <label for="username" class="control-label">Email ID</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailID, new {autofocus = "autofocus",@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Please enter the valid email" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailID, null, new { @class = "validmsg" })
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Please enter password" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "validmsg" })
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="loginErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error hide">Wrong username or password</div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label style="float:left;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember login
    </label>
     <p class="help-block forinfo"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i> if this is a private computer</p>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="LoginFormSubmit" class="btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Script Code:

```
$('#LoginFormSubmit1').click(function (e) {
  if ($("#loginForm1").valid()) {
        $.post('/Account/Login', $('#loginForm1').serialize(), function (data, status, xhr) {
           if (data.Status == 0) {
                debugger
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Home/index",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: { "City": localStorage.getItem('popState') },
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger
                    var IS_JSON = true;
                    try {
                        var result = $.parseJSON(response);

                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        IS_JSON = false;
                    }
                    if (!IS_JSON) {

                        $("#myList").html('');
                        $("#myList").html(response);
       }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
                });
                     }
             else {
                debugger
                $('#alertbox').show();
                $('#Statsmessage').text(data.StatusDesc);

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#myModal").hide();
                }, 2000);

            }

        })
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: *It is not working when I click the login button* getting any error ?

Comment: When I click login first time is not working after Click second time working good.No error shown.

Comment: *Please check your console log.*

Comment: I checked but am not getting any error

Comment: *alert after button clicked* Is your click fired first time?

Comment: yes first time fired. i think script side have problem

Comment: Is your ajax creating a call to your method?

Comment: My ajax call Working Good